# Limit to number of items in Flash context menu?

Tags: flash, actionscript-3

Is there a limit to number of items that can be added to Flash ContextMenu, I am trying to add 16 items but only 15 are displayed.

Please let me know if there is an alternative?

Thanks.

Comment: Here is the link to code that should generate add 100 menu items but it stops at 15 http://pastie.org/1101540

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the Flex Language reference its clear that Flash player can't have more than 15 menu items, here is the link for same - 
http://livedocs.adobe.com/flex/3/langref/flash/ui/ContextMenu.html

Answer (score 0):

its possible to make sub menu on AIR platform
http://www.adobe.com/livedocs/flash/9.0/ActionScriptLangRefV3/flash/display/NativeMenu.html#addSubmenu()

also I found this helpful too
http://code.google.com/p/custom-context-menu/

Comment: Thanks for sharing this...i want to achieve this in Browser plugin..looks like which is not possible.

Comment: Yes, Yogesh, its limited in direct way. You can use components from my previous answer, or look for "Menu" word in http://code.google.com/p/flexlib/wiki/ComponentList

But if you'll run this - http://pastebin.com/4H1jmXh0, you'll find that customItems is okay as array, so its limited by graphical design of ContextMenu.

Also you can post this like a bug on bugs.adobe.com/flashplayer